# How to sort Integers from Files

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to take input from File1(.txt) and File2(.txt), combine and sort the Integers contained in both files and create a third File3(.txt), containing the sorted integers from files 1 and 2.

Here is my code so far:

```
    File input1 = new File("H:\\Desktop\\input1.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input1);

    File input2 = new File("H:\\Desktop\\input2.txt");
    int num;

    while(scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        num = scan.nextInt();

        final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(num);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

File1 contains numbers 10, 11, 8, 74, 16.
Every array I try, I have always gotten Gibberish output, So I have resulted in this code. I get output but its not sorted:

```
[10]
[11]
[8]
[74]
[16]
```

Can anyone help and or give advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move your list outside the loop so it's  not initialized every time. Also remove the `final` keyword since it will change in size.
2. To add to a `List<Integer>` use `.add(element);`. This will add a new element to the end of the list.
3. Repeat this logic for the second file.
4. Call `Collections.Sort(list);` When you are done populating the list.
5. Create the new file. Loop through the list and write the elements to the file
6. Close the file

Check it out below. (I don't have a Java compiler atm so it might not work) Hopefully you get the idea.

```
File input1 = new File("H:\\Desktop\\input1.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input1);

File input2 = new File("H:\\Desktop\\input2.txt");
int num;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(scan.hasNextInt())
{
    num = scan.nextInt();
    list.add(num); 
}
scan = new Scanner(input2); // Point Scanner to new file    
while(scan.hasNextInt()) // Loop through new file
{
    num = scan.nextInt();
    list.add(num); 
}
Collections.sort(list); // sort list after populating it from both files

// Printing to file
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
for(int numberInList : list) { // Loop through sorted list and print out list to file
    writer.println(numberInList);
}
writer.close(); // Close the file
```

Comment: Most of this code works i just have problems with the list: List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(); , saying its abstract and cannot be instantiated, as well as: for(int num : list) , num has already been declared can i use a different integer?

Comment: @Tyler I updated the code. Use `new ArrayList<Integer>();` instead of `new List<Integer>();` Just change the name of `num` in the `for` loop. I changed it to `numberInList`

Comment: Alright now i get output, but after changing the inputs 1 to 10, and 2 to 11, the output has given me 11, 11  : PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("H:\\Desktop\\output.txt", "UTF-8"); , anything wrong here and or any ideas?

Comment: Changing the numbers in the file to `1 2 3 ... 10` in the first file and `2 3 4 ... 11` in the second file? What does the error say specifically?

Comment: Just purely 10 in input1.txt and 11 in input2.txt, there is no error message but the output.txt contains 11, 11, rather than printing 10,11, acting as if its not taking input from input1.txt and printing input2.txt twice.

Comment: Can't say what would cause the problem. Just make sure that the file structure is the same for both files. Also it might help to print out the contents of the `list` after adding to it from each file. `for(int n : list) { System.out.println(n); }` Check to see if the numbers are being added correctly.

Comment: @Tyler If you are using commas to separate the numbers, you have to remove them. Place `scan.useDelimiter("\\D");` after `Scanner scan = new Scanner(file1);` and after `= new Scanner(file2);` to remove any non-numerical characters from the input. This might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i just realized i was printing num instead of printing NumberinList into the file, all good now!